# About isomorphism of $PGL(2)$ and $SO(3)$

Tags: algebraic-groups, gr.group-theory

I need to prove that $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})\cong SO_3(\mathbb{R})$. Abstract considerations show that both can be identified with the group of projective motions of a conic curve. But maybe there is more explicit isomorphism (in matrix form, for example)?

Comment: This is not really a research question, so I'm inclined to vote to close.  However, before doing that, I should ask you whether you really mean $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ or not?  I think you might mean $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$ instead.

Comment: BTW:  I would suggest asking this question on math stack exchange, since it is a standard kind of question for that site.

Comment: Dear Robert: For a non-degenerate quadratic space $(V,q)$ over a field $k$, usually ${\rm{SO}}(q)$ denotes the algebraic $k$-group classifying automorphisms of $(V,q)$ (over extensions of $k$).  If $q$ is the standard split quadratic form $q_n$ on $k^n$ ($x_1 x_2 + x_3 x_4 + \dots + x_{n-1}x_n$ for even $n$, $x_0^2 + q_{n-1}$ for odd $n > 1$), it is common for algebraists to write ${\rm{SO}}_n$ to denote ${\rm{SO}}(q_n)$.  So for $k = \mathbf{R}$, the Lie group ${\rm{SO}}_n(\mathbf{R})$ is not the same as ${\rm{SO}}(n)$. And ${\rm{PGL}}_2 = {\rm{SO}}_3$ as algebraic groups (over any $k$)!

Comment: @nosr: Thanks for pointing this out; I wasn't familiar with this convention among algebraists (which would be very confusing for geometers if they were to try to adopt it). Since the title of the question used '$\mathrm{SO}(3)$', I assumed that it was interchangeable (in the OP's mind) with $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$ (a notation I did not use in my comment). Would $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ also mean $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$ to you? How would you denote $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$? Also, your definition confuses me a bit because it seems to be what I would denote as $\mathrm{O}_3$.  How do you get the '$S$'?

Comment: I think nosr neglected to include the condition that the automorphisms have Dickson invariant 1 (equivalent to determinant 1 when 2 is invertible).

Comment: Dear Tim, There is a three dimensional irrep. of $PGL(2)$, given by the symmetric square of the standard rep. of $GL(2)$.  This gives a map from $PGL(2)$ to $GL(3)$, which must be an injection, since $PGL(2)$ is a simple adjoint group.  It suffices to show that the image preserves a non-degen. quadratic form (since then we will get an embedding of $PGL(2)$ into $SO(3)$, which will be an isomorphism for dimension reasons).  For this, consider $Sym^2$ of the three dimensional rep'n.  A simple calculation with weights shows that this rep'n contains a unique copy of the trivial rep'n.  ...

Comment: ... This gives a quadratic form preserved by $PGL(2)$.  A direct computation (if you like) gives that it is non-degenerate.

If follow this through carefully, you will get explicit formulas. Regards, Matthew

Comment: @Emerton, just to mention (as you of course know), the 3-dimensional irrep to which you [refer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128401/about-isomorphism-of-pgl2-and-so3#comment330992_128401) is also the adjoint representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the bilinear form $\langle, \rangle$ on $2 \times 2$ real matrices by setting $\langle A,B \rangle = {\rm tr}(AB).$ The space of matrices breaks with respect to this form as the orthogonal direct sum of the space of scalar matrices and the $3$-dimensional subspace of matrices of trace zero. Now ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts by conjugation on the the matrices of trace zero, and preserves this bilinear form in that action. Furthermore, scalar matrices (and nothing more) in ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are in the kernel of this action, so the action is really one of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{R}).$ Every matrix in ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ has the eigenvalue $1$ in this action- a scalar matrix certainly does and any non-scalar matrix $A$ fixes the matrices of trace zero in ${\rm span}(I,A).$ Every element of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts with determinant $1$ in this action, as diagonal elements clearly do.
This gives an embedding of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ in the special orthogonal group determined by this form,and dimension shows that it is surjection.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the choice of bilinear form is not *ad hoc*:  aside from being the obvious one to choose, it descends to a multiple of the Killing form on $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb R) \cong \mathfrak{pgl}(2, \mathbb R)$.