# Principled construction of the quaternions

Tags: projective-geometry, quaternions, clifford-algebras

Is there a construction of the quaternions that doesn't proceed through generators and relations, and which makes the connection with 3D rotations clear?

I'm not happy with Clifford Algebra as an approach, as that also uses generators and relations.

I have one in mind myself, which is constructing the quaternions as the unique coordinate system for 3D rotations with the following properties:

- The coordinates form a set equal to $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$.
- All coordinates are arbitrarily close to some other coordinate that represents a rotation. In particular, this allows for zero divisors to *maybe* exist.
- If $v$ represents a 3D rotation, then any $\lambda v$ where $\lambda$ is a non-zero scalar, represents the same rotation. The motivation for this axiom is that we want to find a *projective* coordinate system for 3D rotations.
- The composition of rotations corresponds to a *bilinear* product between coordinates. In particular, such a product consists of only the operations $+, \times, -$.

One can show using a long calculation that the quaternions are the only coordinate system that satisfies the above axioms.

Comment: Isn't it going to be quite important what *structure* (algebraic and topological) you want on quaternions?

Comment: @AndrejBauer For axiom 2, I assume the usual Euclidean topology.

Comment: In which case, the axiom states that every open set contain a point that corresponds to a valid rotation. Maybe "corresponds to" is vague

Comment: For a construction of the quaternions, I just want to construct them as an algebra where the conceptual connection with 3D rotations is clear, and which isn't pulled out of a hat

Comment: In applications like computer graphics, quaternions are often criticised for being unintuitive. These criticisms could be answered by a "principled" construction of them

Comment: Ok, so for instance you don't particularly care that they form a complete meric space? You're shooting for the algebraic structure, and in particular the relationship with rotations, is that it?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes

Comment: One way to attack such a question is to identify the structure of interest as the unique (up to isomorphism) one having a certain universal property. Then different proofs of its existence will give different constructions of it. What is the universal property of quaternions, expressed so that it relates to rotations?

Comment: Maybe this link will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: I don't understand your objection to Clifford algebras. Suppose I want an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $R$ which (1) has an element $s_{\vec{v}}$ for each vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (2) the addition and scalar multiplication of $R$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compatible, in the sense that $\vec{v} \mapsto s_{\vec{v}}$ is a linear map and (3) for a unit vector $\vec{v}$, we have $s_{\vec{v}}^2 = 1$, which is what you would expect if $s_{\vec{v}}$ is a reflection. Then you have just defined the Clifford algebra. (continued)

Comment: When $n=3$, we have $R \cong \mathbb{H} \oplus z \mathbb{H}$, where $z$ is a central element corresponding to negation in $O(3)$. The unit vectors in $\mathbb{H}$ then give rotations and the unit vectors in $z \mathbb{H}$ give reflections.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer so you're endowing the reflections with a vector space structure. That is an interesting way to think about it

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I guess my problem with that idea is: What does it mean to add a reflection to a scalar? The advantage of starting with a transformation group and building a "projective coordinate system" for it is that you know what each point in the coordinate system represents. It always represents some transformation (or a degenerate one if it's a zero divisor). You don't formally add scalars to vectors without any understanding of what that might mean

Comment: My axiomatic approach is based on observing that if we want to represent *affine transformations* using matrices, then we need to treat the matrices as ratios. It then makes sense that if we want to represent the group of rotations, we might also use ratios. My approach effectively pre-supposes what the transformation group should be, whether they be affine transformations or 3D rotations or translations, and then builds a Clifford algebra where almost every element has a well-specified geometric meaning

Comment: But it's possible that the question is too vague to get an answer

Comment: @DavidESpeyer is that clear or not?

Comment: One idea is to invert the compact version of the [map from PGL(2) to SO(2,1)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/128401/6518)

Answer (score 10):

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$This is an answer to flesh out what I wrote in comments. Let $V$ be a real vector space with positive definite inner product. For a unit vector $\vec{u} \in V$, let $s_{\vec{u}}$ be the reflection over $\vec{v}$. Here is something we might hope for:

> **Vague hope:** Can we build a ring $R$ whose additive structure comes from the vector space $V$ and whose multiplicative structure comes from multiplying the reflections $s_{\vec{u}}$ in the orthogonal group $O(V)$?

Note that, in particular, if we want multiplication to come from $O(V)$, we should have $\vec{u}^2 = 1$.

More precisely,

> **Precise idea:** Can we find an $\RR$-algebra $R$ which contains $V$ as a vector subspace, such that $\vec{u}^2=1$ for every unit vector $\vec{u} \in V$?

Well, if we ask for a linear map from $V$ to $R$ rather than insisting on a subspace, we can clearly do this. We simply define $R$ by generators and relations. This is why I don't understand the OP's objection to generators and relations: They are the correct tool whenever you want to build an algebraic object that has certain elements in it with certain properties.

> **Definition:** Let $R$ be the $\RR$-algebra generated by $V$, subject to the relations $\vec{u}^2 = 1$ for every unit vector $\vec{u}$ in $V$.

The ring $R$ is the Clifford algebra, and it clearly has an $\RR$-linear map $V \to R$. It isn't obvious that this map is injective, but that is a lemma which you can find in any textbook on Clifford algebras, so I'll omit it. (The more precise statement is that, if $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_n$ is any basis for $V$ then the $2^n$ products $e_{i_1} e_{i_2} \cdots e_{i_k}$ are a basis of $R$.)

Let's connect this to the standard definition. For any vector $\vec{v} \in V$, we can write $\vec{v} = c \vec{u}$ where $\vec{u}$ is a unit vector and $c \in \RR_{\geq 0}$. Since we asked $R$ to be an $\RR$-algebra, we have $\vec{v}^2 = (c \vec{u})^2 = c^2 = |\vec{v}|^2$. For any $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$, we then have
$$\vec{v}^2 = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v},\ \vec{w}^2 = \vec{w} \cdot \vec{w},\ \mbox{and}\ (\vec{v}+\vec{w})^2 = (\vec{v}+\vec{w}) \cdot (\vec{v}+\vec{w}).$$
Subtracting the first and second equation from the third,
$$\vec{v} \vec{w} + \vec{w} \vec{v} = 2 \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}. \qquad (\ast)$$
Here the left hand side is multiplication in the ring $R$ and the right hand side is dot product. That's the more usual definition of the Clifford algebra. (Some people choose the opposite sign convention, $\vec{v} \vec{w} + \vec{w} \vec{v} = - 2 \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}$. I don't have a firm opinion, but I started writing the answer this way, so I'll stick to it.)

Then a miracle happens! For any unit vector $\vec{u}$ and any vector $\vec{v}$, write $\vec{v} = \vec{v}^{\parallel} + \vec{v}^{\perp}$, where $\vec{v}^{\parallel}$ is parallel to $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}^{\perp}$ is orthogonal. We have $\vec{u} \vec{v}^{\parallel} = \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{v}^{\parallel} \vec{u}$, because $\vec{v}^{\parallel} = (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}) \vec{u}$ and $\vec{u}^2 = 1$. Equation $(\ast)$ also gives $\vec{u} \vec{v}^{\perp} = - \vec{v}^{\perp} \vec{u}$. So we have
$$\vec{u} \vec{v} = \vec{u} \left( \vec{v}^{\parallel} + \vec{v}^{\perp} \right) = \left( \vec{v}^{\parallel} - \vec{v}^{\perp} \right) \vec{u} = - s_{\vec{u}}(\vec{v}) \vec{u}. \qquad (\dagger)$$

Let $\vec{u}_1$, $\vec{u}_2$, ..., $\vec{u}_k$ be any sequence of reflections and let $g$ be the product $s_{\vec{u}_1} s_{\vec{u}_2} \cdots s_{\vec{u}_k}$ in the orthogonal group $O(V)$. Then using $(\dagger)$ repeatedly gives
$$\vec{u}_1 \vec{u}_2 \cdots \vec{u}_k \vec{v} = (-1)^k g(\vec{v}) \vec{u}_1 \vec{u}_2 \cdots \vec{u}_k. \qquad (!)$$
Let $\mathrm{Pin}(V)$ be the subgroup of the unit group of $R$ generated by the unit vectors $\vec{u}$. It is easy to see that there is a group map $\texttt{sign} : \mathrm{Pin}(V) \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ with $\texttt{sign}(\vec{u}) = -1$ for every unit vector. Then equation $(!)$ tells us that there is a map $\pi: \mathrm{Pin}(V) \to O(V)$ with $\pi(x)(\vec{v}) = \texttt{sign}(x) x v x^{-1}$.

In this sense, we have fulfilled our hope: $V$ is a vector subspace of $R$, and the fact that $\pi$ is a map of groups tells us that any multiplicative identities that hold between the $\vec{u}$ in $R^{\times}$ also hold between the $s_{\vec{u}}$ in $O(V)$.

The ring $R$ decomposes as $R_+ \oplus R_-$ where $R_+$ is spanned by products of an even number of vectors and $R_-$ uses an odd number. The subgroup $\mathrm{Spin}(V) = \mathrm{Pin}(V) \cap R_+$ maps to $SO(V)$, so this is where to look for rotations.

---

So far, $V$ can have any dimension. Now we specialize to $\RR^3$, with orthogonal basis $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$. It is easy to check that the elements $e_1 e_2$, $e_2 e_3$ and $e_1 e_3$ multiply by the same relations as $i$, $j$ and $k$ in the quaternions and, in fact, $R_+ \cong \mathbb{H}$.

The special magic thing that happens in the quaterions is that $\mathrm{Spin}(\RR^3)$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{H}$. In general, $\mathrm{Spin}(\RR^n)$ is an $\binom{n}{2}$-dimensional submanifold of a $2^{n-1}-1$ dimensional unit sphere in $R_+$. It is only when $n=1$, $2$ or $3$ that $\binom{n}{2} = 2^{n-1} - 1$.

Comment: So the relation $\vec v^2 = 1$ is motivated by trying to treat the $\vec v$s like reflections. And then everything happens to work out

Comment: That's how I think about it! It's pretty amazing that just imposing $\vec{u}^2=1$ and the ring structure is enough to force all other multiplicative relations between $\vec{u}$'s in $R^{\times}$ to also hold in $O(V)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a modified version of the axioms above. We want a coordinate system for 3D rotations with the following features:

1. The coordinates form a set equal to $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$.
2. All non-zero coordinates represent some rotation.
3. Every rotation is represented by some coordinate.
4. If $v$ represents a 3D rotation, then any $\lambda v$ where $\lambda$ is a non-zero scalar, represents the same rotation. The motivation for this axiom is that we want to find a *projective* coordinate system for 3D rotations.
5. The composition of rotations corresponds to a *bilinear* product between coordinates. In particular, such a product consists of only the operations $+, \times, -$.

Let $\mathbf 1$ be the coordinate for a null rotation, $i$ be the coordinate for a half-turn around the $\vec i$ vector, and $j$ and $k$ be likewise for the $\vec j$ and $\vec k$ vectors. This all follows from axiom 3.

Let's consider the point $i$. Immediately, it's clear that $i^2 = \lambda \mathbf 1$ for some scalar $\lambda$. This scalar could be anything at this point except $0$.

By axiom (1) and (2), every non-zero linear combination of $\mathbf 1$ and $i$ represents some rotation. It is *weird* to take linear combinations of projective coordinate, but it is certainly *possible*, and it allows us to narrow down the space of possibilities. We see that these linear combinations generate a 2D algebra. It turns out there are only three 2D algebras up to isomorphism: The complex numbers, the dual numbers, and the split-complex numbers. We see that up to isomorphism, the algebra we've generated *must* be the complex numbers as the other ones contain zero divisors, and all rotations are invertible. Alternatively, we may argue using the *orders* of the elements: Rotations contain elements of any order.

The subalgebra generated by $\{\mathbf 1, i\}$ must correspond to some continuous subgroup of the 3D rotations. The only such subgroups that exist are rotations about some axes. Since $i$ represents a rotation about the $\vec i$ axis by a half turn, the group we've generated must be the set of all rotations about $\vec i$.

A similar argument applies to $j$ and $k$.

Finally, what is $ij$? Well, for geometric reasons it must be $\lambda_{ij} k$ for some scalar $\lambda_{ij}$. Moreover, we have $(iji^{-1})^2 = ij^2i^{-1}=-1$; so $\lambda_{ij}=\pm 1$. By geometric considerations also, $ji = \lambda_{ji}k$, and we can likewise conclude that ${ji} = \pm k$. Finally, we conclude that $i$ and $j$ anti-commute by starting with $(ij)^2 = -1$ and rearranging to get $ij = -(ij)^{-1}=-j^{-1}i^{-1}=-ji$.

## What's the motivation?

Essentially, I posit that a transformation group can often be endowed with a coordinate system or representation. This coordinate system is either *cartesian* or *projective*.

A Cartesian coordinate system for a transformation group is one where (except for a negligible subset) all elements of $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$ are in one-to-one correspondence with that transformation group. We insist that the product be bilinear. The rotation-dilation group can be represented by the Cartesian coordinate system $\mathbb C$. The complex number $i$ now represents a quarter-turn.

In fact, the classic examples of Cartesian systems for transformation groups are rings of square matrices.

Now consider as an alternative *projective* coordinate systems for transformation groups. Here, a scalar multiple of a coordinate represents the same transformation. Again, we insist that almost all elements of $\mathbb R^n$ stand for some element of the group, and that the product be bilinear.

The classic example is the matrix representation of the group of *affine transformations*. Here, the matrices are specified *up to a ratio*. We are generalising this because we may want our coordinate system to be more specific for computational efficiency and accuracy reasons.

The complex numbers $\mathbb C$ are also a *projective* coordinate system for rotations (not dilations). But then $i$ represents a half-turn, not a quarter turn.

[Removed a subjective remark that's perhaps non-mathematical. If someone who's seen it thinks it's appropriate to include it here, then I might do that].

Comment: This is nice too! For general $n$, I would much rather start with the reflections than the rotations but I see that, when $n=3$, it is nicer to send a unit vector $u$ to the half twist $-s_{\vec{u}}$ around $u$.

Comment: To see what this looks like for $n=4$, suppose we wanted $t_{ij}$ to be the half twist in the $(i,j)$ plane for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$. Then $t_{ij}$ would be $e_i e_j$ in my coordinates. We have $t_{ij}^2 = -1$ and $t_{ij} t_{jk} = t_{ik}$ as in your answer, but we need to introduce a new element $t_{1234}$ to be $t_{12} t_{34}$. Also, for an element $b_{\emptyset} + \sum b_{ij} t_{ij} + b_{1234} t_{1234}$ to give a rotation we need impose not only that $b_{\emptyset}^2+\sum b_{ij}^2 + b_{1234}^2=1$ but also a second condition that I don't know explicitly.

Comment: You haven't determined whether $ij=+k$ or $ij=-k$ (that is, the chirality of quaternions). Of course they're isomorphic by conjugation... I was going to comment in favor of Clifford algebra (bivectors vs vectors/"right hand rule"), but there is still the same choice/ambiguity of whether to use $QvQ^{-1}$ or $Q^{-1}vQ$...

Comment: @mr_e_man I guess you could define $k:=ij$. Then my argument shows that $k$ has all its desired properties

Comment: $(1+k)/\sqrt2$ represents a quarter-turn around the $\vec k$-axis; but there are two such rotations. Is it clockwise or anticlockwise? ...Anyway, this probably isn't the right place to discuss this.